# jooq schema not beeing added to my SQL

Tags: java, sql, schema, jooq

I am trying to use jooq as a SQL generator only, but I cannot seem to get the Schema information to be added to my query:

```
private String getOtmUserReportSql() {

    Settings settings = new Settings().withRenderMapping(
            new RenderMapping().withDefaultSchema(Constants.REP));
    DSLContext create = DSL.using((Connection) null,SQLDialect.ORACLE,settings);
    String sql =
    create.
            select(
            DSL.fieldByName("User Id").as("User_ID"),
            DSL.fieldByName("User_Name").as("Full_Name"),
            DSL.fieldByName("Active Status").as("Active_Status"),
            DSL.fieldByName("Email").as("Email"),
            DSL.fieldByName("Last Login Time").as("Last_Login_Time"),
            DSL.fieldByName("Role").as("Role6"),
            DSL.fieldByName("ID_ROLE").as("Role_Id"),
            .from(DSL.tableByName(REP)).getSQL();

    LOGGER.info("Generated SQL : {}",sql);
    return sql;
}
```

the SQL generated is:
2013-08-12 17:52:12,008 [INFO] [main] c.j.i.x.c.i.SimpleJDBCReportService[67] : Generated SQL : select "User Id" "User_ID", "User_Name" "Full_Name", "Active Status" "Active_Status", "Email" "Email", "Last Login Time" "Last_Login_Time", "Role" "Role6", "ID_ROLE" "Role_Id", "Business Group" "Business_Group", "Menu Template" "Menu_Template" from "REP"

according to the documentation present on http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.5/manual-single-page/#runtime-schema-mapping i should see something like:
MySchema."User Id" ... MySchema.REP

I am using version 3.1, any assistance is greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings.defaultSchema` may imply that this schema name is added to every table and column, but that's not the case. The default schema is used to *omit* rendering of a *"default"* schema name, in case you're using generated tables and column objects. In other words, if you set up your connection to have a default schema, you can tell jOOQ that it doesn't need to render that schema any more.

While I can see some potential in generically adding schema names through jOOQ's exposed SPIs, I'm not sure if that's so easy to do, if you're not using the code generator.

The simplest solution is to just qualify your table reference: [`DSL.tableByName()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#tableByName%28java.lang.String...%29)

```
DSL.tableByName("MySchema", REP)
```

Comment: Thank you lukas, i added the DSL.fieldByName(Constants.REP,"User_Name"), and it generated the SQL as expected.